# how can i implement a javascript function to just print the content of <div class="clear TmarginXlg paddingLg">...</div>

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="unit size3of5">
                        <div class="letterBody paddingLg LmarginXlg">

                <?php 
                    if (strpos(strtolower($philosophies[0][bg_img]), '.png')) $remote = false;
                        else $remote = true;

                    ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo base_path().$directory; ?>/img/logo.png" width="100" class="floatL" alt="..." />
                            <div class="salonLogo floatR">
                                <img id="salonLogo" src="<?php echo base_path().$directory;?>/img/clientToolBox/salonLogo.jpg" class="" alt="..." />
                                <span class="miniFog">&nbsp;</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear TmarginXlg paddingLg">
                                <p class="upperC paddingLg BpaddingSm" id="PpressName"><?php echo t($webform['components'][4]['value']); ?></p>
                                <p class="paddingLg BpaddingSm" id="PpressLocation"><?php echo t($webform['components'][5]['value']); ?></p>
                                <p class="paddingLg BpaddingSm" id="PpressDesc"><?php echo t($webform['components'][6]['value']); ?></p>
                                <p class="paddingLg BpaddingSm" id="PpressContactName"><?php echo t($webform['components'][7]['value']); ?></p>
                                <p class="floatR paddingLg BmarginXlg" id="PpressContactNum"><?php echo t($webform['components'][8]['value']); ?></p>
                                <p class="BmarginXlg">&nbsp;</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would jQuery's $.html() function give you the result you're looking for?

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) , you could use:

```
$(".clear.TmarginXlg.paddingLg").text();
```

That would return you all the text inside the div you mentioned and all of its children's text.

You could do this with jquery or any other javascript library, unfortunately I'm only familiar with jquery.

If you don't want to use a javascript library, you would have to iterate over the children of that DIV and concatenate their text nodes manually.

Comment: I want to send it to the printer !

Comment: If that's the case... I think that the only option is using `window.print()`. The problem is that this method prints everything on your browser's window. If you need to print selectively, I would create a new window in which only the content I need to print appears and add a `window.print()` call to that page.